# Windows игнорирует некоторые записи файла Hosts

Tags: windows, windows-7, dns

Собственно проблема... С недавнего времени перестали работать некоторые записи Hosts-файла. Хотя наверно весь файл перестал работать кроме записи localhost. При пинге адресов прописанных в нем резолвятся внешние ip. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой? Система - Windows 7 Ultimate (6.1.7601)

P.s. В DataBasePath все правильно вроде: %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc (REG_EXPAND_SZ)

Comment: Убери все, кроме localhost, поработай (перезагрузись) и глянь, не пишутся ли наново неправильные адреса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы не пробовали сделать видимыми скрытые и системные файлы? Бывает иногда подцепишь такую гадость, которая оставляет ваш исходный файл, переименовывая его в нечто очень схожее, но, например, с русской буквой "о". А новый, с верным названием, кладет туда же, делая его скрытым. Так же в нем есть кое-какие дополнительные строки, аля Вконтакте с новыми адресами и т.п.

Comment: Нет. Дополнительных строк нет. Скрытые и системные файлы включены. Русских букв в имени нет. Результат один и тот же. Пробывал сбрасывать все настройки сетевой карты и все равно не хочет работать...

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Все заработало. Как ни странно помогло восстановление системы.